# How to create a Json File in memory from javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, fileapi

I have a backend endpoint that only accepts a json file. The user is supposed to upload a Json file and then the application submits this file to the endpoint and it works fine. Now I would like to use the same endpoint to upload json files created by the code, I would like for example to take the following javascript object

```
{
    name: 'Brian',
    age: 40
}
```

and transform it into a File object, so that I can submit it as a file, not as an object.
I have tried to use the File Api constructor like this:

```
    new File([{ name: 'Brian', age: 40 }], "file.json", { type: "application/json" });
```

but the endpoint does not accept it, I assume the first argument is not in the right format... should it be a blob instead?

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
const jsn = JSON.stringify(YOUR_OBJECT);
const blob = new Blob([jsn], { type: 'application/json' });
const file = new File([ blob ], 'file.json');
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: I believe you can also do `const file = new File([ JSON.stringify(YOUR_OBJECT) ], 'file.json', { type: 'application/json' });`